# html actionlink attributes

Tags: c#, html, actionlink, html.actionlink

I have onde question, in my code above, the two first pages works in perfect way, but the last one only show one page with only one line with the code specifics. I need help!!

```
 @if (((RegisteredUser)Session["User"]).IsExpert)
{
<li>@Html.ActionLink("Área técnica", "Index", "Dashboard", new { area = "Expert" }, null)</li>
}
@if (((RegisteredUser)Session["User"]).IsServiceDeskAdmin)
{
<li>@Html.ActionLink("Área de administração", "Index", "Dashboard", new { area = "Administration" }, null)</li>
}
@if (((RegisteredUser)Session["User"]).IsExpert)
{
<li>@Html.ActionLink("Perfil", "Index", "PerfilController", new { area = "Perfil" }, null)</li>
}
```

The code above is the .cs file. Thanks

```
     using System;
     using System.Collections.Generic;
     using System.Linq;
     using System.Net;
     using System.Net.Http;
     using System.Web;
     using System.Web.Mvc;

    namespace Fcebi.ServiceDesk.WebPlatform.Controllers
     {
      public class PerfilController : Controller
      {

   // GET: Perfil
     protected override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        base.OnActionExecuted(filterContext);
        Fcebi.ServiceDesk.WebPlatform.Areas.Expert.ExpertAuth.DoAuth(Session, Request, filterContext, Url);
    }
    public ActionResult Index(String Id)
    {
        // Id = api da tabela User
        Id = "Id7dkSro7Qh";
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(Id) || String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Id))
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "O ID do utilizador tem de ser definido");
        }
        else
        {
            try
            {

                RegisteredUser U = RegisteredUser.FindByAPI(Id);

                var JsonToReturn = new
                {
                    Name = U.Name,
                    Departamento = U.Department,
                    Email = U.Email,
                    signature=U.Signature
                };
                return Json(JsonToReturn, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }

            catch (ServiceDeskException Ex)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult((int)Ex.ErrorId, Ex.Message);
            }
            catch (Exception Ex)
               {
                new ServiceDeskException(ServiceDeskException.ErrorList.OTHER, Ex);
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, Ex.Message);
               }

           }
        }
     }
  }
```

Comment: Your wording isn't clear. Do you mean the _link_ doesn't display properly, or the _page that's rendered by clicking on the link_ doesn't display properly? I've no idea what you mean by "only one line with the code specifics"

Comment: The link does not work 100 % , the page is not redirected , and when I force the link to go to the page only appears a line of information with the user information , and I would like to show the well-configured page , I copy and pasted the code of pages that work and so changed the variables and what I wanted to show

Comment: what does the rendered html of the actionlink look like? Does that correspond to a real controller and action in your application?

Comment: It's like one blank page with the information in one line, and don't, the real controller is a html page with the default layout and information i need to show. But the two page on the link ("Expert" and "Administration") it's works

Comment: no i was asking what the rendered html of the _actionlink_ looks like. And I'm asking if it's definitely pointing to the right place?

Comment: Yes, my name file is "PerfilController"

Comment: In that case shouldn't it be `@Html.ActionLink("Perfil", "Index", "Perfil", new { area = "Perfil" }, null)`. That's the difference between this one and the others. You don't need to append "Controller" to the string. That's why I've been asking you to show me the HTML rendered by the ActionLink, so we could check it was really a valid link.

Comment: send me your e-mail and i send you the file, it's more easy

Answer (score 1):

Try changing

```
@Html.ActionLink("Perfil", "Index", "PerfilController", new { area = "Perfil" }, null)
```

to

```
@Html.ActionLink("Perfil", "Index", "Perfil", new { area = "Perfil" }, null)
```

I don't think you should be appending "Controller" - MVC will work it out.

Secondly, your .cs Index method is returning JSON. So if you go to that action in the browser you'll just see the JSON as text. It's not returning a webpage. So what you're doing creating a link to it doesn't make much sense - it looks like it's designed to be called via Ajax.

Comment: he redirected  to another page.

Comment: @ThiagoSchettiniMari I don't understand. "he redirected to another page"? Who did? Where did it redirect to? P.S. re your other comment I'm not giving out my email address to strangers, with all due respect, sorry. Maybe paste the PerfilController.cs with the Index method into your question. Also your route config would be useful. And lastly, again I will ask to see the _rendered HTML_ that the ActionLink turns into :-)

Comment: that was my code in the index.@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Perfil";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
    ServiceDeskConfig Config = new ServiceDeskConfig();
    RegisteredUser User = (RegisteredUser)Session["User"];
}
<div class="well well-sm text-center">Dados do Utilizador @User.Name</div><script>$('button[role="submit-ticket"]').on('click', function () { SubmitPerfil(); });
        });
        function SubmitPerfil() {
            if (ServiceDeskFormValidator()) {
               var Data = new FormData();
                $.ajax({url: '@Url.Content("~")/Perfil/Index',

Comment: what was?  I don't see it

Comment: paste into the question please (as I requested). Large blocks of code in comments are unreadable :-)

Comment: also I asked for the .cs code but that looks like Razor/javascript.

Comment: Ok thanks. That method returns JSON. So if you view that in the browser it'll just be a load of text. It's not returning a webpage.

Comment: If it's possible you can add one exemple please? :)

Comment: It that you just told me to change

Comment: you've already got an example of an ajax call to this method - you posted it in the comments on this very thread a couple of hours ago!

Comment: I need use .append with contains my html? I am a little bit confuse now... Sorry that

Comment: you posted the snippet `$.ajax({url: '@Url.Content("~")/Perfil/Index` . I don't know where that is in your solution, and it's half a snippet but it gives you a clue how to call the URL via ajax, so you just need to finish that off and call it from wherever is meaningful. That will return the JSON containing the user object, and then I presume you'll want to populate some UI with the resulting information. If you have no idea what I'm talking about I suggest you read some tutorials on working with ajax and JSON.